# Better precision with Arduino (floats)

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, arduino-uno, temperature

I'm trying to do the Steinhart-Hart temperature calculation on an Arduino. The equation is [image]

I solved a system of 3 equations to obtain the values of A, B and C, which are:

```
A = 0.0164872
B = -0.00158538
C = 3.3813e-6
```

When I plug these into WolframAlpha to solve for `T` I get a value in Kelvins that makes sense:

`T=1/(0.0164872-0.00158538*log2(10000)+3.3813E-6*(log2(10000))^3) solve for T`

`T = 298.145 Kelvins = 77 Fahrenheit`

However when I try to use this equation on my Arduino, I get a very wrong answer, I suspect because doubles do not have enough precision. Here's what I'm using:

`double temp = (1 / (A + B*log(R_therm) + C*pow(log(R_therm),3)));`

This returns 222 Kelvin instead, which is way off.

So, how can I do a calculation like this in Arduino?? Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `log2` denotes the base-2-logarithm, and `log` the "natural" or base-e-logarithm. That might already explain the difference.

Comment: Also `C = 000003.3813` and `3.3813E-6` are not the same number.

Comment: Yes, here `ln` probably refers to the neperian logarithm, which would be `ln(x) = log2(x) / log2( exp(1) )`

Comment: `log(R_therm)` --> `(log(R_therm)/log(2))`

Comment: @chux, more like `(log(R_therm)/log( exp(1) ))` (or replace exp(1) by `2.7182818284...`)

Comment: @MayeulC `log( exp(1) ))` is 1.0.

Comment: @chux, try it, `exp` is the exponential function. It equals `e`, which is the aforementioned constant.

Comment: @MayeulC `ln` always refer to the natural neperian logarithm. In C it's called `log`

Comment: @MayeulC in `C`, as this post is tagged `log(x)` and as used in OP's code snippet --> "The log functions compute the base-e (natural) logarithm of x." C11 7.12.6.7  Try `printf("%e\n", log(exp(1)));`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, @chux, you are both right, and my bad for confusing this. I didn't see the `log` in @chux previous comment. I apologize. I am afraid I did too much maths and not enough c lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precision is not the main issue.  Could even use `float` and `powf()`.  A thermistor temperature calculation is not *that* accurate.  After all the temperature is certainly not better than [±0.1°C accurate](http://www.omega.com/prodinfo/thermistor.html).  Self heating of the thermistor is a larger factor.

OP's C code assumes log base 2, use log base *e* `log()` as the constants were derived using log base 2.  [@Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653265/better-precision-with-arduino-floats/39653790#comment66609383_39653265)

```
// double temp = (1 / (A + B*log(R_therm) + C*pow(log(R_therm),3)));
double temp = (1 / (A + B*log(R_therm)/log(2) + C*pow(log(R_therm)/log(2),3)));`
```

Sample implementation, that avoids an unnecessary slow `pow()` call.

```
static const inv_ln2 = 1.4426950408889634073599246810019;
double ln2_R = log(R_therm)*inv_ln2;
double temp = 1.0 / (A + ln2_R*(B + C*ln2_R*ln2_R));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, floating point arithmetic has limited precision on most arduinos.

Have you considered using fixed precision? If used correctly, this might give you better results. The requirement for this is to have rather narrow parameters, however, and be careful about unit conversions.

An `unsigned long` on arduino is 4 bytes too, so it can contain numbers up to `2^32-1`. If using fixed point, you might want to replace this `1/T` by something like `100000/T`, where the numerator constant and T have been scaled according to the desired precision.

You will also need to keep a (mental or paper) model of the number of decimals each variable contains, in order to optimize the operation order not to lose precision.

For the `log2` function, I doubt it is available out of the box for integers. You could either cast the result or [reimplement it](http://programmizm.sourceforge.net/blog/2011/find-integer-log-base-2-of-an-integer). There is plenty of ressources for this problem, even here on SO.

Comment: I would say that floating-point arithmetic has limited precision not just on most Arduinos, but on all of them, and on all other computers too...

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Every number representation has limited precision at some point, if you want to nitpick. But avr-based arduinos only have 4-bytes floating point numbers. No double precision. The Due has double precision floating point numbers, for example. But this might net be the issue here.